# Replace an element's class with another class

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Incredibly simple question, but a combination of beer and football is leaving me hopelessly inadequate! ( bound to be a duplicate too, but I can't for love nor money find it )

I have an element

```
<div class="inline-block" id="colour">
```

I would like to check if the class contains bg-anycolour ( ie. bg-red or bg-yellow or bg-blue and so on )

if not add class bg-colour ( again bg-colour could be bg-red or bg-white or bg-pink and so on )

if true replace bg-anycolour with bg-colour

I know I am looking for regex match contains and replace, but not to be constrained by any other classes that might be added at a later date.

```
    function setColour(colour) {
    //need to add class br-{colour} but also to remove colour if already there
    if ($("#colour").attr("class").match(/(** what goes here **)/))
    {
       ** and replace?? **
    }
    else
    {
        $("#colour").addClass('bg-' + colour)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: If `.bg-anycolour` is *not* present then add `bg-colour`, if it *is* present then replace `bg-anycolour` with `bg-colour`? Why are you not simply: `$('#colour').addClass('bg-colour').removeClass('bg-anycolour');`? I could be misunderstanding your criteria/requirements, but so far as I can tell (from reading your question) regular expressions are needlessly complicated and completely redundant to achieve this.

Comment: It's not really clear, but I'm guessing `cbg-colour` is really something like `bg-yellow`, `bg-red` etc. as you're using regex ?

Comment: Hi, I haven't explained that well, bg-anycolour could be any colour ie bg-red, bg-blue etc. and if, say, bg-red exists replace with bg-yellow.

Comment: And so what would `bg-colour` be? I...could you put together some sort of demonstration/information showing possible scenarios and what should happen? Even an ascii table of some sort might help, currently I'm just confused.

Comment: We can select elements with jQuery using start-with selector $("div[class^='apple-'],div[class*=' apple-']")
But I dont think jQuery.removeClass() parameter can be given selector that remove class start-with bg

Comment: I have it sorted now thanks, post answer when the 8 hours are up. but once I found a match I could do $("#colour").removeClass(regex.exec(str)[0]); str being the entire value of the class attribute. and regex being /bg-\w+/;

Comment: Hope the beer was better than France were :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the clarifications in your questions, and the comments, as well as your own posted answer, it *seems* that the question you're asking is:

> how can I find a class-name with the format `bg-<colourName>` and replace that `<colourName>` portion with a new, given, colour-name if it exists, and *adding* `bg-colourName` if it doesn't exist?

With that in mind -and I'm curious as to the use-case because it *seems* unnecessarily complex- I'd suggest the following approach:

```
function setColour(colour) {
    $('#colour').attr('class', function (i, oldClasses) {
        return 'undefined' === typeof oldClasses ? 'bg-' + colour : oldClasses.replace(/\b(bg-[a-z]+)\b/i, function (a) {
            return 'bg-' + colour;
        });
    });
}
```

[Representative JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2jM3x/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [Conditional ('ternary,' `assessment ? ifTrue : ifFalse`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
  - [JavaScript regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).
  - [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).
- jQuery:

  - [`attr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: The useage was to have a list of available colour setting buttons, click one, that sets background colour and saves to server. I am using metroui css [link](http://http://metroui.org.ua/) and rather than function setColour(colour){
    document.getElementById("colour").style.backgroundColor=colour;
}​ which would mean writing all the hex codes out, I thought it would be easier to swap out the class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted, apologies for the clarity of question.

```
    function setColour(colour) {

    //check if class exists that has pattern bg-w+
    if ($("#colour").attr("class").match(/bg-\w+/))
    {
        var str = $("#colour").attr("class");
        var regex = /bg-\w+/;
        //get match and remove
        $("#colour").removeClass(regex.exec(str)[0]);            
    }
    //always add the new class
    $("#colour").addClass('bg-' + colour);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//need to add class br-{colour} but also to remove colour if already there
  function setColour(colour) {
    var ele = $("#colour");
    var classname = ele.attr("class") || "";
    var classStartIndex = classname.indexOf("bg-");
    var classEndIndex = -1;
    if (classStartIndex >= 0) {
        $.each((classname.substring(classStartIndex, classname.length)).split(""),
        function (i, val) {
            if (val == " ") {
                classEndIndex = i;
                return;
            }
        });

        if (classEndIndex == -1)
            classEndIndex = classStartIndex.length;
        else
            classEndIndex = classStartIndex + classEndIndex;

        ele.removeClass(classname.substring(classStartIndex, classEndIndex));
    }
    else {
        ele.addClass("bg-" + colour)
    }
}
```